# How to force Cura to walk through a layer in one run?

Tags: ultimaker-cura

I already tried a lot settings in Cura and try to search for a solution but without success. Maybe someone got this issue and solved it.

I want to prevent Cura from printing such gaps at the wings to make it in one run. With ironing one run would (hopefully) bring better results. See the animation for what I mean.

[image]

Why want to do this? I hope to prevent thes ironing issues shown in the following pic.

[image]

Comment: There's no way to do this in Cura. Could you perhaps describe (and show a photo of) the print quality problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Are you asking it to print straight across the gap, retracting the filament there instead of making the extra pass on the other side?

Comment: @DoxyLover yeaht that´s what I want.

Comment: The photo is really unclear (extreme low resolution, out of focus, blurred) and you still haven't explained what you want and what the problem is. Is this layer the ironing layer and something about returning looks cosmetically bad?

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of a general solution.

For your specific issue, try rotating the object 90 degrees around the z-axis.

Answer (score 2):

[This answer](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/14394) hints to changing the print orientation to prevent the slicer to create "pockets" that are filled later. But, since we cannot see the rest of the design, or for more complex designs, it is possible that you cannot change the orientation. Maybe concentric pattern will help you, but that doesn't always works or looks fine.

However, there is a way to solve this (but it requires a different slicer then Cura) using the upcoming release of PrusaSlicer as discussed during [Prusa Live #3, live stream @ June, 17 2020](https://youtu.be/NAW2JR-D_QU?t=35m35s) under "Ironing & Monotone infill". The monotone infill will fill in the "pockets" in the same direction to prevent defects caused by build-up of filament at the wrong side. This feature may be very useful for better filling in layers.